# Is there a guideline for the maximum buffer size I send over a socket?

Tags: sockets

Sorry if this question has been asked before (I could not find any questions similar to mine), but is there a "maximum" buffer size that I should be sending over a socket at one time? If I were to for example send over data with a buffer size equal to that of the maximum allowed by sockets, would there be anything bad about that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of sockets. With TCP a connection is a byte stream and the OS will take care of how best to split the bytes into packets and concatenate these together at the other side.

With UDP instead each `send` will result in a single UDP message (datagram) and there is an upper limit of 64k for the size of a datagram. But even while UDP supports 64k datagrams in theory it is not a good idea to use that large messages. Since the maximum transfer unit of the underlying layer is much smaller (like around 1500 bytes for Ethernet) the message needs to be fragmented and it is easy to loose a single fragment - in which case the whole message is considered lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can send as much data as you want - that's the point of the abstraction. The underlying layers will do what they want, breaking things into chunks as necessary, but you shouldn't have to care about that as a user of the interface. The `read` and `write` interfaces both will return the length actually transmitted in the case of a partial read, so a simple loop should be sufficient to do a large transfer.